# Why Unix.tm_hour is the real hour minus one?

Tags: ocaml

The current time here is `11:05`, If I do `Unix.gmtime (Unix.time())`, I get

```
{Unix.tm_sec = 53; Unix.tm_min = 4; Unix.tm_hour = 10; Unix.tm_mday = 19;
 Unix.tm_mon = 5; Unix.tm_year = 113; Unix.tm_wday = 3; Unix.tm_yday = 169;
 Unix.tm_isdst = false}
```

The `Unix.tm_hour=10`, but it should be 11, right?

**Why it is the real hour minus one?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because it's summer and UNIX is still using GMT (so will be one hour out once the clocks go forward).

Comment: what do you mean by this? I thought GMT will follow UK's time?

Comment: GMT does not shift by one hour in the spring. It stays the same. In the UK, we shift to BST (British Summer Time) in the spring and back to GMT in the autumn. Simply put, your locale has Unix.gmtime stick to GMT through the whole year.

Comment: ahhh, ok. I thought UK rules the world and GMT follows along

Comment: ;-) We do; and we have 0 longitude passing through Greenwich. I can pardon your bug though; your wouldn't know it was summer in the UK by looking out the window.

Comment: As far as I know, it's not GMT but UTC.

Answer (score 1):

You should use Unix.localtime () to get the local time, the time returned by Unix.gmtime will be different from your local time depending on which timezone you are in.